# Bash - Added new user, Now unable to locate package

Tags: bash

Can someone explain this to me please.
Why when logged in via root, can I issue `ifconfig` and it executes. 
While after creating a new user and I issue `ifconfig` it is unable to locate the package.

Bash Output

```
user@hostname:~$ ifconfig
bash: ifconfig: command not found
user@hostname:~$ locate ifconfig
/sbin/ifconfig
user@hostname:~$ /sbin/ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.121  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe2e:b2d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:2e:0b:2d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2476  bytes 228711 (223.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1942  bytes 275732 (269.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

What I believe the difference is, is privileges?
I.e. sbin - Root requirements

Just on some systems of mine, I can issue ifconfig without the requirement of Sudo.

So why just specifying the path sbin can I execute something that is really requiring root privileges?

Am a bit confused, or is it my users are configured incorrectly by allowing sbin execution?

First Debian based system (Am a arch user and never been faced with this before)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by the default `PATH`: `root`'s default `PATH` includes `/sbin`, standard users' default `PATH` doesn't. Compare the contents of `/etc/profile` and `/root/.profile`...